# Dell Precision T7600 OMSA Perc H710

Tags: dell-perc, dell-openmanage

Due to recent hardware failure in my RAID 5, I need to re-think my monitoring strategy.

My inherited "servers" are a pair of Precision T7600 workstations running Auto DJ radio software that requires Ubuntu/Debian (Unsupported by Dell).

The pair each have a RAID 5 configured with 4 2TB disks. Previous problems with this setup forced us to upgrade the default 310 Perc, to a H710 Perc.

I've now setup my failed primary with a boot drive for the OS running the needed software, and my 5TB RAID drive mounted for data. This is working, I just need to monitor these drives.

I've installed the OMSA from here: http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/ubuntu/ 
The installation went smoothly, but I'm seeing this used mostly with Poweredge servers, not workstations.

Here are the result of some common commands with OMSA:

```
# /opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/srvadmin-services.sh restart
DSM SA Connection Service is already stopped
Stopping Systems Management Data Engine:
Stopping dsm_sa_snmpd: Not started * 
Stopping dsm_sa_eventmgrd: Not started * 
Stopping dsm_sa_datamgrd: Not started * 
Stopping Systems Management Device Drivers:
Stopping dcdbas: * 
Stopping dell_rbu: Not started * 
Starting Systems Management Device Drivers:
Starting dcdbas: * 
Starting dell_rbu: * 
Starting Systems Management Data Engine:
Failed to start because system is not supported
Starting DSM SA Connection Service:  *

# omreport chassis info
Error! Chassis info setting unavailable on this system.

# omreport storage controller
No controllers found
```

Is it possible to monitor the Perc controller with this configuration? My other option might be to install ESX to both these systems and run Ubuntu as a VM. I've read here: http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/Common/dell-opnmang-sw-v7.4_User%27s%20Guide2_en-us.pdf how to install on ESX, but would my hardware be supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The H710 is a re-branded LSI, so you can use [MegaCLI](https://askubuntu.com/q/488612) to get the status of your drives.

---

On a related note, RAID 5, with four 2TB disks, and I am assuming that these disks are SATA disks, is not a very good idea, because in the event of a disk failure, the rebuild time on those 2TB disks is going to be high enough that the chance of another disk failing *during* the rebuild is very high.

If you can, get two more drives and convert the array to RAID10

Comment: Thank you for the MegaCLI link, I have not seen this tool before. I know RAID 5 really isn't the best option, but it is my only option right now because of the vast music library. I can't put more disks in the RAID because there aren't enough available slots inside the case. I'll look into hardware that could help.

Comment: We converted our system to a RAID 6 with the same disks.

Comment: Following the instructions here: https://calomel.org/megacli_lsi_commands.html There is an awesome bash script called lsi.sh that gives me everything I need!! Thank you.

Comment: @BrandonMartin RAID6 with 4 disks gives you the same usable space as RAID10, but with degraded performance. RAID10 is a much more sensible solution if you have 4 disks. The advantage is that you can expand the array by one disk at a time I guess, which you can't usually do with RAID10 (you have to expand it 2 disks at a time).